# jQuery regex, remote with validation

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    jQuery("#regform").validate({
        rules: {
            NickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                remote : "user_availability.php",
            },
        },
        messages: {
             NickName:{
                      required: "<br>Please enter your username",
                      minlength : "<br>Your username must be at least 2 characters long",
                      remote: "<br>This username is not available, please try another"
                     }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When I try to add any addMethod regex examples found on here it will not work

this is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function() {

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var check = false;
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);



    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    jQuery("#regform").validate({
        rules: {
            NickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                remote : "user_availability.php",
                regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$",
            },
        },
        messages: {
             NickName:{
                     required: "<br>Please enter your username",
                     minlength : "<br>Your username must be at least 2 characters long",
                     remote: "<br>This username is not available, please try another"
                     regex: "Invalid Character",
                    }    
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

please help

Comment: check your console / debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a `,`

```
remote: "<br>This username is not available, please try another" <<<<<
```

and you dont need a ',' on the last element of your objects:

```
NickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                remote : "user_availability.php",
                regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$",
            },   <<<<<<<
```

---

**Personally i would make the whole think alot neater**

```
var ValidationObject = {
    rules: {
        NickName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote : "user_availability.php",
            regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$",
        }
    },
    messages: {
        NickName:{
            required: "<br>Please enter your username",
            minlength : "<br>Your username must be at least 2 characters long",
            remote: "<br>This username is not available, please try another",
            regex: "Invalid Character",
        }
    }
}
```

Then use like so:

```
jQuery("#regform").validate(ValidationObject);
```